# Border style based on standard control causing runtime error

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, border, basedon

I created a new WPF project by Blend 2017 (.net 4.7) with one window and this Xaml (added no code behind):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="_borderStyleWithChildBinding"
               TargetType="{x:Type Border}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Border}}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Child.Fill}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Width="50"
          Height="30"
          Margin="10">
        <Border BorderThickness="5"
                Style="{StaticResource _borderStyleWithChildBinding}">
            <Border.Child>
                <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="10"
                           Fill="Green" />
            </Border.Child>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It compiles but reports a runtime error concerning line

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Border}}"
```

**Exception:** `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:` A value for `System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder` caused an exception.

**InnerException:** Resource `System.Windows.Controls.Border` cannot be found.

The designer is smart enough to show the right thing:[image: Border with child binding]

Comment: My guess is, there is no default style for Border defined since there is none listed here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=vs.110).aspx - if you simply omit the BasedOn attribute of your style, it should work though

Comment: @Markus Dietrich: Tried it but the border does not appear, only the designer is working correctly.

Comment: The exception is correct - there is no default style for Border, so the resource lookup fails.  The designer warns you about this in the "Error List" window.

Comment: The designer shows the "right thing" only because it initializes elements in a different order than runtime does.  At runtime, the binding activates when the Style is applied, before Border.Child is set.  The binding finds Border.Child==null, and sets Border.BorderBrush to its default value.  The designer apparently reverses the order, activating the binding after Border.Child is set.  BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(border, Border.BorderBrush).UpdateTarget() nudges the binding to try again, which works.  (This doesn't happen when Child is set because Child doesn't raise a change event)

Comment: @MarkusDietrich: Thanks for your efforts, please see my answer.

Comment: @SamBent-MSFT: Thanks for your efforts, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the problem by omitting the `x:Key` and the `BasedOn` property of the border style:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" >
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Child.Fill}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Width="50"
          Height="30"
          Margin="10">
        <Border BorderThickness="5">
            <Border.Child>
                <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="10"
                           Fill="Green" />
            </Border.Child>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```